# JAX-WS - Async IO exception in WAS 8.5

Tags: java, websphere, jax-ws

I am getting making a JAX-WS client call to remote server(both WAS 8.5):

```
java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55  The specified network resource or device is no longer available.

    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.<init>(AsyncLibrary.java:891)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary$IOExceptionCache.get(AsyncLibrary.java:904)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncLibrary.getIOException(AsyncLibrary.java:918)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncChannel.multiIO(AbstractAsyncChannel.java:482)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncSocketChannelHelper.read(AsyncSocketChannelHelper.java:217)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioSocketIOChannel.readAIOSync(AioSocketIOChannel.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.processSyncReadRequest(AioTCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:182)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.TCPReadRequestContextImpl.read(TCPReadRequestContextImpl.java:111)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.parseResponseMessageSync(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:1724)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.readSyncResponse(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:745)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.startResponseReadSync(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:1842)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.outbound.impl.HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.finishRequestMessage(HttpOutboundServiceContextImpl.java:1245)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.HttpOutSyncWriter.finishBufferRequest(HttpOutSyncWriter.java:94)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.HttpOutWriter.writeBuffer(HttpOutWriter.java:136)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.out.HttpOutByteBufferOutputStream.finish(HttpOutByteBufferOutputStream.java:468)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendChunkedRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:882)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.sendSOAPRequest(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:799)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.SOAPOverHTTPSender.send(SOAPOverHTTPSender.java:578)
    at com.ibm.ws.websvcs.transport.http.HTTPTransportSender.invoke(HTTPTransportSender.java:366)
```

I have increased for:

```
com.ibm.ws.http.ConnectionIOTimeout = 70s
HttpInboundPersistReadTimeout = 70s
```

and

```
Web container transport chains --> Persistent timeout = 70s
```

When I make a call I get folowing line in the WAS console:

```
[4/20/16 9:56:48:396 CDT] 00000070 WSChannelFram A   CHFW0019I: The Transport Channel Service has started chain HttpOutboundChain:XXX.XXX.XXX:80.
```

time difference is less than 60s, then I get the error...

```
[4/20/16 9:57:39:380 CDT] 00000070 SOAPOverHTTPS E   WSWS7263E: The following exception occured: java.io.IOException: Async IO operation failed (1), reason: RC: 55
```

I tried all the solution in the forums that I could find. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: A good first step is to try to observe it with a packet capture.

Comment: did you find a solution to that ?

Comment: Hi Did you get this work? If So could you please share answer for the same